# selecting the most recent rows from database with multiple return set

Tags: sql, sql-server

Normally I would do

```
select top (1) * from table where id active = '1' and doc_type_id = '404'
```

to get the latest row.

However I'm using IN to get results back. Plus a join.

```
select t1.* 
  from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on (t1.propid = t2.propid)
 where t2.caseid in ('100','101') and t1.active = '1' and b.doc_type_id = '404'
```

This query here returns the documents. However there are multiple documents of the same type.
And if each one has 10 docs I need only the latest one.

I would want to retrieve only the latest 1 doc for each from the database.

I hope I explained myself :)

Comment: The sql type is what tags are for, please do not use the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the return types you are going for, it sounds like you need to use a `GROUP BY` and/or a `MAX`. If that does not help solve your problem, could you please post a sample data set and what you expect?

You might even be able to use [partitioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) and/or [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

**UPDATE BASED ON COMMENTS**

```
WITH myCTE
AS
(
    SELECT t1.*, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t2.caseid ORDER BY LastSavedDate DESC) AS RowNumber
    FROM table1 t1 
        LEFT JOIN table2 t2 
            ON t1.propid = t2.propid
    WHERE t2.caseid in ('100','101') 
        AND t1.active = '1' AND b.doc_type_id = '404'
)
SELECT * 
FROM myCTE
WHERE RowNumber = 1;
```

This MIGHT work for you based on your comments

Comment: We currently have a document database that stores the location of files. Each row is linked to an asset.
Currently there are multiple rows for each document type.

I simply want to get back the latest row.
with this one I'm getting back all the rows of the document type.

The issue i'm having is with the IN. 
It should return 2 rows.
one for 100 and one for 101.
But it's only returning 1 row when I try a group by.

Comment: But, what are your columns? What are you looking to get? a sample dataset (it doesnt have to be real data, just something to give the idea) would be very helpful

Comment: id | propertyid | document_type_id | file_location

1    100          404                C:\f1.doc

2    100          404                C:\f2.doc 

3    100          404                C:\f3.doc

4    101          404                C:\f4.doc
5    101          404                C:\f5.doc
6    101          404                C:\f6.doc
7    101          404                C:\f7.doc

Comment: @user1303402 I have updated my answer so that it might help you in what you are looking for. Let me know if that fits. It sounds like what you are looking for. I had to guess on how you know what the most recent is (using LastSavedDate), but you probably have another way

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Oops, I will fix the answer. I always get caught up with the little syntactical things...no matter how often I do them :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the ideal scenario for **window functions**. They are exactly what you need. Take a look at [`over`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) keyword.